# Why does my IIS URL Rewrite rule match, but doesn't perform the action?

Tags: iis, proxy, rewrite, lets-encrypt

I have a IIS box that is acting as a proxy. In order to use Let's Encrypt, I created a rule that was set to:

Match pattern, Wildcard, pattern = `*/.well-known/*` action, none and `stop processing of subsequent rules` turned on.

despite testing the pattern and seeing that `http://example.com/.well-known/xxx` was a match, the rule never gets hit.

Due to time constraints, I ignored the problem and I simply disabled the rewrite rule once every few months and renew the cert.

After missing one of the renews, I decided to revisit and after Googling a little, I found someone else had a solution which was setting the criteria  to using regex, and the pattern to `\.well-known/acme-challenge/*` with the same action as I have.

I am happy that this worked perfectly, however, considering the one I did was a match in the tester, I just can't understand why the rule didn't work and I was wondering if anyone knows/can explain it?

FYI, here is the web.config extract that didn't work:

```
<rule name="Let's Encrypt" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*/.well-known/*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Comment: `<action type="None" />` if action type is "None", what's the expected result ?

Comment: Hi @Swisstone - Rule 2 is to forward http to https, and rule 3 is to proxy https to the actual site... By having rule 1 and action of none, this is telling it that if the address matches the rule, to do no proxying/blocking or any other action, then to stop processing extra rules.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules